# Find a Square among given Coordinates

Tags: c++, computational-geometry

If I am given 100 points in the coordinate system, and I have to find if there exist a square in those vertices in C++. Is there a way that I can detect a square among those vertices without having to choose all pairs of 4 vertices and then checking distamces of each of them?? Can there be a better algorithm for this? Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: Well since a square requires that an edge have 2 points with the same x or same y, you could try just looking for x or y pairs to reduce the combinations you need to check

Comment: @webchemist but the square need not to be always having vertices with same (x/y)coordinates. I.e. parallel to axis. It may be at an angle to the axis too.

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200331/minimum-number-of-extra-points-needed-to-make-a-square#comment41125932_26200331